# Check if a row with certain values exist, and create if it does not exist

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large table with a couple of thousands of origin points (column A) and a couple of thousands of destination points (column B) and another columns with a value. I need an efficient algorithm in python to make sure that there is a row for each pair of origin to destination, and if not, create it.

For example, imagine I have three origin points (1,2,3) and Three destination points (1,2,3). Currently, my data does not have a row for each possible pair between origins (column A) and destinations (column B) and is like:

```
Index  A      B     Value
0      1      1     V11
1      1      3     V13
2      2      1     V21
3      2      2     V22
4      2      3     V23
5      3      1     V31
6      3      3     V33
```

I want a python script to make it look like:

```
Index  A      B     Value
0      1      1     V11
1      1      2     NA
2      1      3     V13
3      2      1     V21
4      2      2     V22
5      2      3     V23
6      3      1     V31
7      3      2     NA
8      3      3     V33
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way using `itertools.product`.

The idea is to calculate the full set of combinations, remove combinations that already exist, then add the remainder to the dataframe.

```
from itertools import product

maxval = df[['A', 'B']].max().max()

prod = set(product(range(1, maxval+1), range(1, maxval+1)))
existing = set(map(tuple, df[['A', 'B']].values))

additional = pd.DataFrame(np.array(list(prod - existing)), columns=['A', 'B'])

res = pd.concat([df.set_index('Index'), additional], axis=0)\
        .sort_values(['A', 'B'])\
        .reset_index(drop=True)\
        .reset_index()

print(res)

   index  A  B Value
0      0  1  1   V11
1      1  1  2   NaN
2      2  1  3   V13
3      3  2  1   V21
4      4  2  2   V22
5      5  2  3   V23
6      6  3  1   V31
7      7  3  2   NaN
8      8  3  3   V33
```

Comment: This is great and works just as I expected! I appreciate it jpp.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
df.set_index(['A','B'])\
  .unstack()\
  .stack(dropna=False)\
  .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   A  B Value
0  1  1   V11
1  1  2  None
2  1  3   V13
3  2  1   V21
4  2  2   V22
5  2  3   V23
6  3  1   V31
7  3  2  None
8  3  3   V33
```

How it works:

First, you create a MultiIndex.  Use unstack with default level of -1 the inner most index, this creates a matrix with A as rows and B as columns, populating that matrix with the matching Value.  In places where there is no matching value, None/NaN is assigned.  Now, we can use stack with a parameter dropna=False to retain all values include the None/NaN values.

Comment: This the way I will using :-)

Comment: @Wen... Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try `pivot` and `melt`

```
df.pivot(index='A',columns='B',values='Value').reset_index().melt('A').sort_values('A')
Out[338]: 
   A  B value
0  1  1   V11
3  1  2  None
6  1  3   V13
1  2  1   V21
4  2  2   V22
7  2  3   V23
2  3  1   V31
5  3  2  None
8  3  3   V33
```